# Regular expression for matching all variables in a shell script

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Let's assume I have the following string:

```
cd $MY_DIR
This is some text:$MY_VARIABLE
Add some other text $1 $2 $FOO value=$BAR
```

What would be a valid regex to find all occurences of the variables?

I have tried the following expresion but it has some drawbacks as it:

- also selects the blank
- doesn't select `$1` `$2` individually

`\$.*`

Comment: What tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using VS Code. Added the tag to my question.

Comment: Try `\B\$\w+`....

Comment: That would match `\$var` which aren't variable reference though. Maybe with an additional lookbehind, e.g. `\B(?<!\\)\$\w+` ?

Comment: @Aaron The lookbehind  won't solve that anyway. One would need `(?<!\\)(?:\\{2})*\$[a-zA-Z_]\w*`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was mistaken about positional arguments, OP do want to match them. Otherwise I'm not sure why my lookbehind wouldn't work but I trust your expertise :)

Comment: @Aaron I mean that `(?<!\\)` cannot tell ``\\`` from ``\``. It is not possible to avoid matching escaped entities with this single lookbehind.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Right, thanks for explaining !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
\B\$\w+
```

that matches a `$` that is not preceded with a letter, digit or `_` and then 1 or more letters, digits or `_`.

[image]